# How efficient is MEF at loading plugins

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have an application that loads 5-25 plugins at startup and the plugins are running some fairly long-running initializations upon instantiation (1-10 seconds) - this is outside of my control. So the question is if MEF does anything to parallelize loading and instantiation of the plugins.
Right now I use a custom plugin loading system which I would like to replace with something simpler (MEF), but I need to understand the performance implications.

Comment: _to understand the performance implications_ - nothing tell you better than trying to run it with your application

Comment: Yeah, I get that - but since I have the application in the middle I can do the update to MEF and try it with a few dummy plugins. Other teams with their own build systems provides the plugins, so it is not easy for me to update the plugins to use MEF, just to do a test run.